# Label single bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I wonder how it would be possible to add labels to single bars in `ggplot2` as I would like to label my rows in my barplot as Online Broker, Bank, No Account. Thank you for your help!

Here is my code:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library (scales)

plot1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(df$InvA, y = after_stat(prop)), na.rm = TRUE) +
geom_bar() +
scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE) +
ggtitle("Post-Covid") +
xlab("Accounts") +
ylab("Individuals") +
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), limits=c(0,0.8))
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.

plot2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(df$InvAcc, y = after_stat(prop)), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Pre-Covid") +
  xlab("Accounts") +
  ylab("Individuals") +
 scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), limits=c(0,0.8))
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.

grid.arrange(plot2, plot1, ncol = 2)
```

The plot then looks like this:

[image: output]

However, the labels should look like these for my previous plot, but since I managed to get the y-scale to percent, my labels disappeared or it doesn't work to compute the y-scale to percent with the values remaining as factors (Online-Broker, Bank, No-Account) since I had to change them to numeric (1,2,3):

[image: expected]

```
dput(dfaccounts) # (with 1=Online Broker, 2=Bank, 3=No Account)

structure(list(df.InvAcc = c(2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
NA, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 
3L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L), df.InvA = c(NA, 
1L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 2L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 
2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L, 
2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 3L, 
1L, NA, 3L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -133L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you `InvA` and `InvAcc` columns are numerics. Hence, using `scale_x_discrete` the axis text gets dropped.

To fix you issue I would suggest to convert the columns to `factor`s with your desired labels set via the `labels` argument. Additionally, to get the right percentages we have to explicitly set the `group` aes via `group=1`:

```r
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

labels <- c("Online-Broker", "Bank", "No Account")
data$InvA <- factor(data$InvA, labels = labels)
data$InvAcc <- factor(data$InvAcc, labels = labels)

plot1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(InvA, y = after_stat(prop), group = 1), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE) +
  ylim(0, 40) +
  ggtitle("Post-Covid") +
  xlab("Accounts") +
  ylab("Total No. of Individuals") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.

plot2 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(InvAcc, y = after_stat(prop), group = 1), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE) +
  ylim(0, 40) +
  ggtitle("Pre-Covid") +
  xlab("Accounts") +
  ylab("Total No. of Individuals") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.

grid.arrange(plot2, plot1, ncol = 2)
#> Warning: Removed 64 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count).
#> Warning: Removed 69 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count).
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @stefan! you really saved my day, can't thank you enough!